# Use hyperlink in comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Is it possible to make an hyperlink like [this](http://www.endoftheinternet.com/) on a comment?

Comment: [This should halp](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @jadarnel27 - hilarious :P

Comment: Thanks :) Now I know how to do it! This is [me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187730/af)!

Comment: Didn't it cross your mind to click the "help" link to the right, below the "Add Comment" button? The answer is the very first sentence in this help: *Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com)` _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work* (no offence, but clicking help links should be common knowledge :))

Comment: I think [THIS QUESTION](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121422/use-hyperlink-in-comment#comment321705_121422) is the ANSWER to your question :)

Comment: [Trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes. Simply put the text of the link between [ ] and follow it immediately with the URL between ( ), and it will be a link.