# How to link to a particular answer?

Tags: support, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I link to a specific answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer)

A couple of times would have wanted to link to a particular answer, but it seems answers can't be pointed directly using links.

Comment: And for the comments, the timestamp is the permalink.

Answer (score 8):

Yes they can, just click on the `share` link below an answer.

This answer, for example, has the link `http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160263/140890`; the last part is my user id, and can be removed.

Comment: You should close the question as well now ..

Comment: @AshRj: (1) If you want a question closed, flag it as "it doesn't belong here". (2) Why should this be closed?

Comment: @Manishearth I know that, i thought that 10k users could close them on their own (?). 2) Why does this need to be open anymore ? The answer is here and i hardly think there can be anything more 'comprehensive' than this ;) Also, its an extremely narrow situation, that too because the user probably simply missed the `share` button.

Comment: @AshRj: No, 10k users get one close vote per question, like everyone else. (♦ mods can close it with one click). This is not "too localized", otherwise all support qs would be such. A q is too localized if it is about a particular post/particular user and will probably never be applicable again. This one is a easy reference for linking to a post.

Comment: @Manishearth This q is equivalent to asking 'what does clicking on the share button do ?' . I dont think that it is really adding to the content already on the site.

Comment: @AshRj That is not at all what this question is asking. It makes no reference to the share button at all. The question (if it weren't a dupe) is just fine.

Comment: @Manishearth Closing will simply prevent more answers, if i understand correctly and nothing else. And i dont see why any more answers are needed. @Bart `It makes no reference to the share button at all.` Exactly my point. The user probably missed/didn't notice it !

Comment: That is a nonsense reason to close a question. Then we could close every question once the user is told the answer. The question is just fine for Meta.

Comment: @Bart Ok, its probably fine for meta. On a separate note, once a question has been answered completely and thoroughly, why shouldnt it be closed ? Or am i interpreting what 'closing a question' means incorrectly ..

Comment: @AshRj Closing is applied to questions which to some extent (in their current form) don't really belong on the site. And as for answering, you never know who might add a more thorough answer. (Though in this particular case it might not be so likely). I've answered questions correctly and completely, only to be surprised by another answer hours later which was more in depth and canonical than mine. We would have missed out on that excellent contribution, had we closed the question. There is no need to do so.

Comment: @Bart So i am not wrong if i think this should be closed (neither am i  right as you say). Anyways, Bart, Manishearth Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Not that i want to prolong the discussion, but this was not needed -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160265/200868

Comment: @AshRj What's the harm though? It's illustrative. A picture might just be helpful. It's essentially the same answer, but there is nothing bad about the answer itself. And yes, the dupe also contains similar content, but that's besides the point. Once again, this is no reason for the closure of a question.

Answer (score 5):

You can get a direct link to any answer by clicking on the "share" link below it.

> [image]

Then a box will appear with the link in it

[image]

Comment: I guess you spent the past 40 minutes making graphics, and didn't notice the earlier anwer that says the same thing?

Comment: sorry when i clicked there wasnt any answer ... and i have to leave for 40 minute and when i came back ..i just posted answer .... i should have check first... should i delete  ..

Comment: @NullPointer Just leave it. There is no harm done.