# Link to a question, answer or comment

Tags: support, hyperlinks, faq-proposed, permalink

In writing a question, answer or comment, how can I include a clickable link to cross-reference another question, answer or comment?

Comment: No, those things are indeed not mentioned in the help center, or any documentation, and can be found only by trial and error, or searching here. Many of them are mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange)

Comment: See also [Direct Link to a Comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment), [How can I link to a specific answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer)

Answer (score 14):

### Link to a question or an answer

1. Go to the question/answer that you want a link to.

    Look at the end of that posting,
     before any comments or subsequent answers.

    Click  **share** 
     near the lower left corner of the text.
   [<sup>∇</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272427/link-to-a-question-answer-or-comment#comment885262_272508)

    Something like this will pop up:

   > share a link to this question 
   >   **http: //meta.stackexchange.com/q/272427/313009** 
   >              
   >                close
2. Copy 
     **http: //meta.stackexchange.com/q/272427/313009**,
     using your mouse or  Ctrl+A Ctrl+C.
3. Return to the question, answer or comment that you are writing.

    Paste what you just copied, using your mouse or Ctrl+V.
4. Make sure that the resulting 
     **http: //meta.stackexchange.com/q/272427/313009** 
     is surrounded by spaces.
5. That should do it, in a basic way.

    More information is available by clicking  **links** 
     near the top left corner of the area where you are writing.
     If you don't see  **links** , click the  **?** 
     near the top right corner of your writing area.

---

### Link to a comment

1. Go to the end of the comment that you want a link to.

    **Right-click** (or equivalent) the
     date  **Mar 14 '16 at 12:34** ,
     day  **yesterday** ,
     or time lapse  **12 hours ago** :

   > Knock knock - WhoMe  **Mar 14 '16 at 12:34**
   >
   > Who's there? - Horton  **yesterday**
   >
   > Who's on first - WhoMe  **12 hours ago**
2. Choose the popup-menu option 
     **Copy Link Location** 
     (or **Copy shortcut** or equivalent).
3. Return to the question, answer or comment that you are writing.

    Paste what got copied, using your mouse or Ctrl+V.
4. Make sure that the resulting 
     **http: //meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272427/link-to-a-question-answer-or-comment#comment884498_272427** 
     is surrounded by spaces.
5. That should do it, in a basic way.

    More information is available by clicking  **links** 
     near the top left corner of the area where you are writing.
     If you don't see  **links** , click the  **?** 
     near the top right corner of your writing area.

---

#### Further reading

[Editing help, Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links)

[Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/313009)

[How can I link to a specific
 answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242027/313009)

[Add data.SE style “magic links” to
 comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/313009)

[How to reference material written by
 others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)
(Guidelines, at English Language & Usage SE)

[Hidden features of Stack
 Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172459/313009)

Comment: The technique that you describe for comments (right-click and "Copy Link Location" or "Copy shortcut" (or equivalent)) also works on the "Share" links under posts.  I find it more convenient to use one technique consistently, and, if anything, it's less work.

Comment: Comments are not for footnotes. They are temporary messages to ask for clarification on the post.