# How to get an longer link to answers?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, usability

While it's possible to get links to questions and comments that include the title of the question in the link, I haven't seen a way to do this for answers.

Question link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer

Answer link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45598/334717

Comment link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer#comment104234_45598

When commenting code about a particular solution used, I sometimes prefer to link to an answer rather than the question. However I miss the descriptiveness of the overall question link url.

Edit: There is a feature request part to this question. While it possible to click on the title of a question or the time stamp of a comment to get sent to a link, there is no such direct feature for answers. As the [correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281024/how-to-get-an-longer-link-to-answers/281025#281025) to this question suggested, the only way to do so, is to paste and go to the shortlink. Surely if there was a place to click a link for answers, as there is with questions and comments, there might not be a question on [how to link to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer), with 171 upvotes

Comment: You can enter the short link in a site like [this one](http://checkshorturl.com/expand.php) (which expands a short URL) and get the full URL, which does include the title. e.g. for http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45598/334717 it returns http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer/45598#45598

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there an existing meta post about whether something is a duplicate if only half of the question is a duplicate of another question?

Comment: Why half? As far as I can see, it is the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just click the shortlink and copy the text in the address bar :D

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer/45598#45598
```

The format is:

```
{site}/questions/{q-id}/{q-title}/{optional:ans-id}#{ans-id}
```

The `{ans-id}` can be also found in the shortlink, here it is:

```
{site}/a/{ans-id}/{user-id}
```

Comment: Of course, it's the same procedure I use to get a link for comments. Thanks